# W3 Total Cache Error (Amazon Linux OS)

Tags: wordpress, w3-total-cache

I am getting this error even after running `chmod -R 755 wp-config.php`
"FTP credentials don't allow to write to file /var/www/html/wp-config.php"

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `sudo chown -R apache:apache /var/www/html` , if not apache, try www-data as user.
2. service httpd restart
3. deactivate and activate W3 Total Cache plugin.